# Calculate sum of rows above and below a point, and also sum of columns left and right a point

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

Hey guys I am doing a question where I have to find a point in a Matrix A of N x M rows such that

the sum of rows above the point is equal to the sum of row

Consider this example

```
/**
 * A[0][0] = 2    A[0][1] = 7    A[0][2] =  5
 * A[1][0] = 3    A[1][1] = 1    A[1][2] =  1
 * A[2][0] = 2    A[2][1] = 1    A[2][2] = -7
 * A[3][0] = 0    A[3][1] = 2    A[3][2] =  1
 * A[4][0] = 1    A[4][1] = 6    A[4][2] =  8
 * @param matrix
 * @return
 */
```

In this example the if we look at the point A[1][1], it can be said that the row above (sum = 14) is equal to the sum of rows below the point. 
Can anyone help me on this?

I have so far gotten this far. But I know this is a sucky approach.

```
public int solution(int[][] matrix) {
    int rows = matrix[0].length;
    int columns = matrix.length;
    int sumabove = 0;
    int sumbelow = 0;

    for( int i = 1; i < rows; i++  ) {
        for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
            sumabove += matrix[i - 1][j];
            sumbelow += matrix[i + 1][j];
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you want the sum of all rows above? Or only the single row above. The question is quite unclear...

Comment: Calculate `sum` for each row in one loop (`for`), as well as `totalRowsSum`. Then in one more loop compare previous rows `sum` (which increases in every iteration by the `currentRowSum`) with `totalRowsSum - sum`.

Comment: so you want a program that will divide the matrix in 2 so that the top and bottom will have the same sum?

Comment: While looping through each point I want to calculate sum of rows above the point and the sum of rows below that point

Answer (score 2):

The idea is to calculate sum for every row (`int[] rowsSum`) and sum for all rows (`totalRowsSum`). And then to iterate through rows, comparing sum of previous rows (`currentSum`) with sum of next rows (`totalRowsSum - currentSum - rowsSum[i]`).

[Code example](http://goo.gl/8WPPBP).

```
public static int solution(int[][] matrix)
{
    int foundRowNumber = -1;
    int rows = matrix.length;
    int columns = matrix[0].length;
    int[] rowsSum = new int[rows];
    int totalRowsSum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        int rowSum = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++)
        {
            rowSum += matrix[i][j];
        }
        rowsSum[i] = rowSum;
        totalRowsSum += rowSum;
    }
    int currentSum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i ++)
    {
        if (currentSum == totalRowsSum - currentSum - rowsSum[i])
        {
            foundRowNumber = i;
            break;
        }
        currentSum += rowsSum[i];
    }
    return foundRowNumber;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i'd say:
1st: get the sum of the whole matrix

2nd: divide by 2 and store in a var (mid)

3rd: loop it to go down a row each time and it will get the sum of that row and subtract it from the total sum, if it is smaller than the remaining then keeps going, if the remaining number is smaller then (mid) then you went over the middle and you start checking the columns for the row you are in and before in another loop using the same concept

something like this (pseudo code):

```
int sum = matrix.sum();
int mid = sum/2;
int topsum = 0;
int botsum = sum; 
int counter=0;
bool fail = false;

while(topsum!=botsum && !fail) //either break when both top and bottom are same or if there is no middle gorund
{
  int rowsum; //use loop to get the sum of the row
  for(int i=0; i>colLength(); i++) rowsum=+ matrix[counter][i];
  topsum =+ rowsum;
  botsum=-rowsum;
  counter++;

  if(botsum>mid) //if you go over the middle
  {
    botsum=-rowsum; //take it back before last addition acction
    counter --; //go back to the last row;
    //loop
    //here you will start checking columns to get to the middle.
  }
}
```

this was made so that it would get you the cell and not row, but you can change it to your liking.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I was able to do make a solution. But I think I made a mess of the complexity. I was supposed to do in a linear complexity. Anyways my solution is

```
public class MainClass {
static int matrix[][] = {{2, 7, 5}, {3, 1, 1}, {2, 1, -7}, {0, 2, 1}, {1, 6, 8}};

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.print(solution(matrix));
}

/**
 * A[0][0] = 2    A[0][1] = 7    A[0][2] =  5
 * A[1][0] = 3    A[1][1] = 1    A[1][2] =  1
 * A[2][0] = 2    A[2][1] = 1    A[2][2] = -7
 * A[3][0] = 0    A[3][1] = 2    A[3][2] =  1
 * A[4][0] = 1    A[4][1] = 6    A[4][2] =  8
 * @param matrix
 * @return
 */

public static int solution(int[][] matrix) {
    int columns = matrix[0].length;
    int rows = matrix.length;
    int sumRowsAbove = 0;
    int sumRowsBelow = 0;
    int sumColLeft = 0;
    int sumColRight = 0;

    int equilibrium = 0;

    for( int i = 0; i < rows; i++  ) {
        for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
            sumRowsBelow = getSumRowsBelow(i);
            sumRowsAbove = getSumAbove(i);
            sumColLeft = getSumColumnLeft(j);
            sumColRight = getSumColumnRight(j);
            if(sumRowsAbove == sumRowsBelow && sumColLeft == sumColRight) {
                equilibrium++;
            }
            int x = 2;
            x+=2;
        }
    }
    return equilibrium;
}

public static int getSumRowsBelow(int rowNum) {
    int columns = matrix[0].length;
    int rows = matrix.length;
    int sumBelow = 0;
    for( int i = rowNum; i < rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
            if((i+1) < rows){                   
                sumBelow += matrix[i + 1][j];
            }
        }
    }

    return sumBelow;
}

public static int getSumColumnRight(int column) {
    int columns = matrix[0].length;
    int rows = matrix.length;
    int sumBelow = 0;
    for (int j = column; j <= columns; j++) {
        for( int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            if((j+1) < columns){                    
                sumBelow += matrix[i][j + 1];
            }
        }
    }       
    return sumBelow;
}

public static int getSumColumnLeft(int column) {
    int columns = matrix[0].length;
    int rows = matrix.length;
    int sumBelow = 0;
    for (int j = column; j >= 0; j--) {
        for( int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            if((j-1) >= 0){                 
                sumBelow += matrix[i][j - 1];
            }
        }
    }       
    return sumBelow;
}

public static int getSumAbove(int rowNum) {
    int columns = matrix[0].length;
    int rows = matrix.length;
    int sumBelow = 0;
    for( int i = rowNum; i >= 0; i--) {
        for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
            if((i-1) >= 0){                 
                sumBelow += matrix[i - 1][j];
            }
        }
    }

    return sumBelow;
}
```

}
This is a codility question regarding find the number of points (equilibriums) such the sum of elements in rows above the selected point is equal to the sum of rows below the point. And also sum of columns from the left of the selected point is equal to the sum of columns to the right of the point.